# Granting user Owner role on Office 365 group will grant the user Full Control on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, microsoft-teams, modern-team-site

I have created a new MS Teams from office 365 central admin site, where i got those created for me:-

1. SharePoint modern team site.
2. Office 365 group.
3. by default the Office 365 group will be added as a member inside the sharepoint member group. here are the groups on sharepoint:-
   [image]
4. when i click on the SP members group, i found that the office 365 group added inside it:-
   [image]

so i realize that adding users to the Office 365 group will grant them Edit permission on the sharepoint site. but i changed a user role inside Office 365 group from Member to Owner, **but i were surprised that this user got full control on the sharepoint, here is the permission check for the user inside sharepoint advance permission settings**:-
[image]

**Where it say that the user got the full control permission through the sharepoint owner group, although in our case this group is empty**. so what is this group exactly? now if i go to the home site >> site permission >> i will find that there is a group named "m.member owners" which have full control and i can not change his permission,as follow:-
[image]

so could this group represents the Office 365 group's users who have Owner role? and this Owner role will grant users full control on the sharepoint site? if this is the case them why this group does not show inside the sharepoint advance permission settings as in the Office 365 members case (which have the exact same name as the SP members group)?
Thanks

**EDIT**. here is the "site collection admin" screen, which shows that it contain the sharepoint owner group , where in our case this group does not contain any user, but any owner inside office 365 group will get full permission on the SP site through this empty sharepoint owner group,, how come .......
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Anyone who is an Owner of the Group is also a Site Collection Administrator on the SharePoint site. You can change this and remove the Group from the Site Collection Admins, should you wish to.

Comment: this is another weird an over complicated settings we are getting inside Office 365!!!.. now in my case the sharepoint site collection admin contain the sharepoint owners group and again this sharepoint group is empty in our case.. so how come an owner inside Office 365 become a site admin, although the site collection admin screen is not showing this user!!

Comment: Did you check Site Collection Administrators? You didn't show that in your screenshots. But this is expected behavior.

Comment: there is something missing in the whole situation..., i edited my question with a screenshot of how the site collection admin looks like !!! the owner is not there... i hope i could find it...

Comment: It is there. Look at your screenshot. The Group Owner(s) have SCA on that site. Again, this is expected behavior.

Comment: the sharepoint owner group is added inside the SCA (as shown in the screen shot)... but in our case the sharepoint owner group is empty !!!! we have owner inside the office 365 group but we do not have users inside the sharepoint owner group.... this what i am saying ...

Comment: Yes, that is also correct. SCA (which contains the Office 365 Group Owners) has greater permission than the SharePoint Owners group for that site. Again, expected.

Comment: looks confusing, now inside SP site we can explicitly see that office 365 members group are added to SP member group... but there is not any thing called office 365 owner group!!! where is this group?.. and why it is not shown as in the office 365 member group which is explicitly been added to the sharepoint member group.. any explanation?

Comment: now i removed the "Groupname owner" group from the Site Collection Admins section, but still the office 365's users who have Owner role, have Full control on the SP site, so seems this will be the case even if we remove the "Groupname owner" group from the Site Collection Admins section???

Comment: now i removed the "Groupname owner" group from the Site Collection Admins section, but still the office 365's users who have Owner role, have Full control on the SP site, so seems this will be the case even if we remove the "Groupname owner" group from the Site Collection Admins section?